# Sharepoint 2007: Adding a link to left nav bar?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a document library in a sub site. How do I add a link to that library into the root site's left navigation bar?

Dynamic or static links are fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean the Quick Launch (which is the left-side navigation shown in most non-application pages), then click "Site Actions", and choose "Site Settings". Under "Look and Feel", pick "Quick Launch". You can add the sub site's document library as a heading of its own, or as a link underneath any heading (it really doesn't matter too much outside of design perspective). This method is best for static links, of course.

The Quick Launch is not restricted to the current site: you can link any external URL you have. The document library of the subsite, basically, is treated as an external URL to the root site. Just make sure you use the full URL, then there's no chance for failure.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it, if you want to do it programmatically:

```
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                var navigationNode = new SPNavigationNode("stackoverflow","http://www.stackoverflow.com", true);
                web.Navigation.QuickLaunch.AddAsLast(navigationNode);
                web.Update();
            }
        }
```